# struct из bool и int

Tags: c++, c, железо

```
sizeof(int)  = 4;
sizeof(bool) = 1;
```

Их сумма = 5

Теперь:

```
struct test { 
bool a1;
int a2;
}

sizeof(test) = 8;
```

Почему так?

Comment: [Выравнивание](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).